# how to set default focus on C# Winform ToolStripMenuItem when Form Shown?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I want to set default focus on C# Winform ToolStripMenuItem when my form is Shown.  Is this possible or not? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: Saravanan, did u try  my solution or you do not want to go api route ?

Comment: i tried, but some exception about DLLImport statement.reference not included

Comment: ok, for that you need to use using System.Runtime.InteropServices; I have updated my answer as well :)

Answer (score 5):

In the Shown event of your Form, set focus to the containing Toolstrip using Focus(), then use Select() to select the specific tool strip item:

```
    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.toolStrip1.Focus();
        this.toolStripMenuItem1.Select();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor for the Form, after creating your ToolStripMenuItem control, use the instance method  `.Focus();`.  This will immediately give focus to the control.